# SQL SERVER Pagination same result

Tags: sql-server-2012, pagination

I have table like

```
create table #a(cat nvarchar(10), name nvarchar(10))
insert into #a values
('a', 'n1'),
('a', 'n2'),
('a', 'n3'),
('a', 'n4'),
('a', 'n5'),
('a', 'n6'),
('a', 'n7'),
('a', 'n8'),
('a', 'n9')
```

whit all three below queries I give row 2!!! ('a', 'n2')

```
SELECT * FROM #a ORDER BY 1 OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
SELECT * FROM #a ORDER BY 1 OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
SELECT * FROM #a ORDER BY 1 OFFSET 2 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

why?

it seams it because of order by column Cat and Cat has only one value 'a', but in my application it may happen and I must handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your order by is not deterministic(not unique).make them like below..

```
SELECT * FROM #a ORDER BY cat,name OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
SELECT * FROM #a ORDER BY cat,name  OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

;

Comment: I solve my problem with your answer, but still I think sql server has bug!!! because all my three queries has same order .

Comment: Thats not a Bug,Imagine what SQL has to do when order by rows are same and we dont specify ,it can pick any one